# C++ function calling from C# application. Attempted to read or write protected memory Error

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am trying to call a C++ function from C# console application.

Here is the C++ function

```
extern int mpsCheck(mpsHandlePtr handle);
```

where mpsHandlePtr is defined as

```
typedef struct  mpsHandleRec *mpsHandlePtr;
```

In my C# I am using following syntax

```
[DllImport("test.dll", EntryPoint = "mpsCheck", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int mpsCheck(ref System.IntPtr handle);
```

On calling the function I am getting below error:
Attempted to read or write protected memory Error

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: No, if you pass an `IntPtr` as a pointer, don't use `ref`. Use `ref` only if you are passing the struct directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your struct in C# and then pass it to the function. Like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct mpsHandleRec 
{
     // fields go here
}

[DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int mpsCheck(ref mpsHandleRec handle);
```

Or, if you only have an opaque pointer to the struct, you omit the struct declaration and pass the opaque pointer:

```
[DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int mpsCheck(IntPtr handle);
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer. Actually i tried with out declaring ref also Still i am getting same error: Attempted to read or write protected memory Error                                     [DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int mpsCheck(IntPtr handle);